# How to print colored text to the terminal, but non-colored to the file with the same Perl statement?

Tags: perl

I would like to make the Perl program to print text in color to the terminal, but when the output is redirected to the file - the same text should be printed without terminal sequences.

I was surprised that Perl print statements like the following don't do this automatically.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
$Term::ANSIColor::AUTORESET = 1;
print "Do you wish to operate in ";
print BOLD GREEN "(s)";
print "cript mode or in ";
print BOLD RED "(l)";
print "ive mode ? \n";
```

How to print like this in Perl?

(The C++ library [rang](https://agauniyal.github.io/rang/) prints intelligently like I described above.)

Comment: "_was surprised that Perl print statements ... don't do this automatically_" -- Seriously, surprised?  You actually expect a language to decide that it's going to drop your instruction to print in color?  What you quote from C++ is a third-party _library_ that does some such, not the language itself.

Comment: It's a nice idea for a library to support that, though.  (But then again Perl gives you an easy way to do this with `-t`, as in ikegami's answer.)

Comment: Terminal sequences don't make any sense when they are printed into a file, not to the terminal. They just trash log files. So yes, I was surprised that Perl does meaningless and harmful things.

Comment: "_terminal sequences don't make any sense when they are printed into a file_"  -- I can accept that statement (even though a purpose of a log file is probably to be _displayed_ and then those sequences suddenly do make sense as most tools in the console will honor them).  But at any rate, it makes even less sense to expect a _language_ to mess with a programmer's decision of how to print.  Tell me a language that does... (again, your example is of a _library_ that does that, certainly not C++ itself!)

Comment: Not all files are log files.

Answer (score 6):

[`-t`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X) can be used to check if a handle is connected to a terminal.

You could simply place the following before `use Term::ANSIColor`:

```perl
BEGIN { $ENV{ NO_COLOR } = 1 if !-t STDOUT; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution has 'not' in it:

```
BEGIN { $ENV{ NO_COLOR } = 1 if not -t STDOUT; }
```

Comment: Using `not` instead of `!` doesn't change anything in that case.

Comment: @Dada, My post was originally missing the `!`.